# Concatenate multiple files in Azure Blob Storage while copying

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a requirement to copy a set number of Azure blobs from one folder to another so that downstream service can consume them. I have been using Azure Data Factory (ADF) activity "Copy" to do that.

The requirement has recently changed and the other service expects the files to be concatenated into one file (All files in the folder are text files with same layout). I couldn't see any options within the ADF Copy activity to do this. Is there any way achieve this using an ADF activity other than writing scripts in PowerShell or similar?

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible. You need to create custom ADF pipeline component and implement `IDotNetActivity` interface, more precise

```
    public IDictionary<string, string> Execute(IEnumerable<LinkedService> linkedServices,
                IEnumerable<Dataset> datasets, Activity activity, IActivityLogger logger)
            {
//PipelineConfiguration( ... ) // configure your pipeline/activity
// some code if needed 
            do
            {
                BlobResultSegment blobList;
                // Get the list of input blobs from the input storage client object.
                blobList = prodAzureStorageClient.ListBlobsSegmented($"{fileContainer}/{fileMask_ifAny}",
                                                                        true, // Use flat blob listing 
                                                                        BlobListingDetails.Metadata,
                                                                        null, // Max results, null = 5000
                                                                        continuationToken,
                                                                        null, // Blob request options
                                                                        null  // Operation context
                                                                    );
                blobs.AddRange(blobList.Results);

                continuationToken = blobList.ContinuationToken;
            } while (continuationToken != null);

// Read files here and concatenate them by you rules

// Upload concatenated file to Azure Blob Storage
    }
```

Greetings